# How to calculate numbers of days between two dates and subtract weekends DJANGO MODELS

Tags: django, django-models

hope you're all fine!

I have a model called `Vacation` and I'm struggling with one field: `days_requested`, this field is the number days from `vacation_start` and `vacation_end`, it works and gives me an integer as result. The problem I'm facing now is that I need to subtract the weekends (or not count them).

What I have:

```py
vacation_start = '2022-05-20'
vacation_end = '2022-05-24'
days_requested = 5
```

What I'm trying to have:

```py
vacation_start = '2022-05-20'
vacation_end = '2022-05-24'
days_requested = 3

#21/05 and 22/05 are weekends
```

Vacation Models:

```py
class Vacation(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        'departments.Department', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    responsible = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='responsible_vacation')
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES_VACATIONS, default='open')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='created_by_vacation')
    vacation_start = models.DateField(blank=False)
    vacation_end = models.DateField(blank=False)
    days_requested = property(
        lambda self: (self.vacation_end - self.vacation_start).days + 1
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.created_by.first_name + ' ' + self.created_by.last_name)
```

I have tried:

```py
    days_requested = property(
         lambda self: [(self.vacation_start + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).date()
                      for i in range(0, (self.vacation_end - self.vacation_start)) if (self.vacation_start + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).weekday() not in [5, 6].days()])
```

But I get the following error:

`'datetime.timedelta' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

And as I perform operations with the amount of days asked I need to be able to get an integer.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You want to get days between those dates or weekdays between those dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

```
class Model:
    days_requested = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    
    
      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        excluded = (6, 7)
        days = 0
        start_date =self.vacation_start
        while start_date < self.vacation_end:
            if start_date.isoweekday() not in excluded: #if you want to get only weekdays
                days += 1
                start_date+= timedelta(days=1)
         
        self.days_requested=days

        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, unfortunately I get an error: `'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: make sure u are writing save method under your model

Comment: yes I'm, I figured that the problem is in the view (form_valid) but even when I comment the lines that raise the error, it doesn't work it simply stays loading when I make the request for vacation

Answer (score 0):

After Elvin's answer I moved the hole logic to my view and set the logic inside `form_valid` function:

```py
        start = form.instance.vacation_start
        end = form.instance.vacation_end
        delta = end - start
        excluded = (6, 7)
        days = 0
        for i in range(delta.days + 1):
            day = start + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
            if day.isoweekday() not in excluded:
                days += 1
        form.instance.days_requested = days
```

Thank you all.

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please understand my effort and accept my solution